# Get memory info of a service only knowing its name

Tags: delphi, memory-management, service, delphi-2010

Is there any way to get how much memory a service application is using only knowing its service name?

Comment: What do you mean by "service name"? The name of the EXE file, the name provided in the second parameter to `CreateService`, or the display name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you must retrieve the Pid of the associated process to the service using the [QueryServiceStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function or the [Win32_Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI Class and then you can use the [GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to Collect the Memory Usage Information of the process.

Check this sample App

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants,
  Windows,
  psApi,
  SysUtils;

function  GetPidFromService(const ServiceName : string) : DWORD;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery(Format('SELECT ProcessId FROM Win32_Service Where Name="%s"',[ServiceName]),'WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  if oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 then
    Result:=FWbemObject.ProcessId;
end;

procedure MemoryInfoService(const ServiceName : string);
var
  hProcess : THandle;
  ppsmemCounters: PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS;
  cb: DWORD;
begin
  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ or PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, GetPidFromService(ServiceName));
  if hProcess <> 0 then
  try
   cb:=SizeOf(PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS);
   GetMem(ppsmemCounters, cb);
   try
   if  GetProcessMemoryInfo( hProcess, ppsmemCounters, cb) then
   begin
      Writeln( Format('PageFaultCount: %d',[ ppsmemCounters.PageFaultCount]));
      Writeln( Format('PeakWorkingSetSize: %d',[ ppsmemCounters.PeakWorkingSetSize]));
      Writeln( Format('WorkingSetSize: %d',[ ppsmemCounters.WorkingSetSize]));
      Writeln( Format('QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage: %d',[ ppsmemCounters.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage]));
      Writeln( Format('QuotaPagedPoolUsage: %d',[ ppsmemCounters.QuotaPagedPoolUsage]));
      Writeln( Format('QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage: %d',[ ppsmemCounters.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage]));
      Writeln( Format('PagefileUsage: %d',[ ppsmemCounters.PagefileUsage]));
      Writeln( Format('PeakPagefileUsage: %d',[ ppsmemCounters.PeakPagefileUsage]));
   end;
   finally
     FreeMem(ppsmemCounters);
   end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
  end;
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      MemoryInfoService('FirebirdGuardianDefaultInstance');
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have delphi-specific code to do this, but i can tell you what windows api calls to make to do this (specifically the toolhelp dll calls). to do this you need to know the name of the exe (not sure if that works for you).

1. use **createtoolhelp32snapshot**, then **process32first** and **process32next** to locate the process ID.
2. get a handle to the process by passing the process id to **OpenProcess**
3. pass the process handle to **GetProcessMemoryInfo**. this will fill a **PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS** structure with the information you're looking for (the workingSetSize structure member).

Answer (score 0):

1. [How can I find the process id from the service name/handle in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469494/how-can-i-find-the-process-id-from-the-service-name-handle-in-delphi)
2. [`GetProcessMemoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find out process metrics

Comment: Answert that are just links are not answers. With your rep I would have expected you to know that... ;)

Comment: I'd mark this as duplicate, but it is not a copy. It is a combination of two existing answers instead. Copy pasting is hardly a better guide than a link to comprehensive response.